# D3 Donut Chart Enter with Transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been working from this D3 block http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799.

I have the code pretty much the way I want it. Except the chart only animates when part of the data set is shared.  If the the dataset contains no labels in common, the graph is simply swapped out.  How do I make it do a growing arc transition from the beginning so the user always knows when new data is presented? I am taking this snippet out of an angular directive so it might not stand quite on its own, fyi.

```
        var padding = 0;
        var height = 350;
        var width = 450;  

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+ width  +' '+ height)
            .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
            .append("g")


        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "slices");
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "labels");
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "lines");


        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
            .innerRadius(radius * 0.6);

        var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
            .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + element.parent().height() / 2 + ")");

        var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

        var color = d3.scale.category20b();

        var dataset = [
            {
                label: "SUPPLY",
                percentage: "22",
                value: 10621
            },
            {
                label: "FROZEN",
                percentage: "22",
                value: 17621
            }
        ];


        render(dataset);


        function render(data) {

            /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
            var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
                .data(pie(data), key);

            slice.enter()
                .insert("path")
                .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
                .attr("class", "slice");

            slice       
                .transition().duration(1000)
                .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                    this._current = this._current || d;
                    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                    this._current = interpolate(0);
                    return function(t) {
                        return arc(interpolate(t));
                    };
                })

            slice.exit()
                .remove();

            /* ------- TOOLTIP  -----------*/

            var tooltip = d3.select(element.parent()[0])                               
                .append('div')                                                
                .attr('class', 'donut-tip bodhi-tooltip');

            tooltip.append('div')
                .attr('class', 'bodhi-tooltip-text');

            slice.on('mouseover', function(d) {
                tooltip.select('.bodhi-tooltip-text').html(d.data.label + '</br>' + d.data[scope.tooltipKeyOne] + "%" + '</br>' + "$" + (d.data.total / 100).toFixed(2));
                tooltip.style('display', 'table');
            });

            slice.on('mouseout', function(d) {
                tooltip.style('display', 'none');
            });    

            /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

            var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
                .data(pie(data), key);

            text.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.label;
                });

            function midAngle(d){
                return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
            }

            text.transition().duration(1000)
                .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
                    this._current = this._current || d;
                    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                    this._current = interpolate(0);
                    return function(t) {
                        var d2 = interpolate(t);
                        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                        return "translate("+ pos +")";
                    };
                })
                .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
                    this._current = this._current || d;
                    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                    this._current = interpolate(0);
                    return function(t) {
                        var d2 = interpolate(t);
                        return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
                    };
                });

            text.exit()
                .remove();

        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heart of the problem is there's no starting point for **entering** slices to tween from.  That said, I'd really simplify the tween code a bit:

```
  slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .attr("class", "slice")
    .each(function(d){
      this._current = { //<-- give the entering slices a starting point
        startAngle: d.startAngle, //<-- have them "grow" from nothing
        endAngle: d.startAngle
      }; 
    });

  slice
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      var endAt = { //<-- have the arc end where it's supposed to
        startAngle: d.startAngle, 
        endAngle: d.endAngle
      };
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, endAt);
      this._current = endAt; //<-- store this for next cycle
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    })
```

---

Full working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var padding = 0;
    var height = 350;
    var width = 450;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
      .append("g")


    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "slices");
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "labels");
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "lines");


    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.6);

    var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
      .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var key = function(d) {
      return d.data.label;
    };

    var color = d3.scale.category20b();

    update();

    setInterval(update, 2000);

    function update() {
      
      var someData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < Math.random() * 10; i++){
          someData.push({
            label: "Slice " + i,
            percentage: "22",
            value: Math.random()
          });
      }
      render(someData);
    }

    function render(data) {

      /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
      var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(data), key);

      slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d.data.label);
        })
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .each(function(d){
          this._current = {
            startAngle: d.startAngle, 
            endAngle: d.startAngle
          };
        });
        
      slice
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
          var endAt = {
            startAngle: d.startAngle, 
            endAngle: d.endAngle
          };
          var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, endAt);
          this._current = endAt;
          return function(t) {
            return arc(interpolate(t));
          };
        })

      slice.exit()
        .remove();

      /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

      var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(data), key);

      text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.data.label;
        });

      function midAngle(d) {
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
      }

      text.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
          this._current = this._current || d;
          var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
          this._current = interpolate(0);
          return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
            return "translate(" + pos + ")";
          };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d) {
          this._current = this._current || d;
          var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
          this._current = interpolate(0);
          return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
          };
        });

      text.exit()
        .remove();

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Mark, your a savior